# kotlin add elements in array as sections

Tags: arrays, listview, kotlin

Can anyone teach me how to initiate/add items in array as section? 
something like - array[["john"],["daniel"],["jane"]]
tried a few like `var d = ArrayList<CustomClass>(arrayListOf<CustomClass>())`
that does not work. 
for example, if i add "david" i want it look like array[["john"],["daniel", "david"],[“keith"]] by finding the index of array contains letter "d"

how can i display them on a custom base adapter / listview? currently using a viewHolder

```
val viewHolder = ViewHolder(row.name) to display.
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is a rule to combine two items in one array? Why "david" was put with "daniel" in the same array?

Comment: why should "David" and "Daniel" be in the same group, but "Jane" and "John" should not? Is there any additional logic other than grouping by the name's first letter?

Comment: Sorry i’ve changed jane to keith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am right, you're trying to create an ArrayList that contains other ArrayLists. So writing:

```
var d = ArrayList<CustomClass>(arrayListOf<CustomClass>())
```

Won't work because the type of the main ArrayList is not String, but ArrayList. So you need to write:

```
var names = ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>()
names.add(arrayListOf("jane", "john))
```

Regarding the second question, check out this course that has a section about RecyclerView: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud9012 If you are a beginner, I strongly encourage you to follow the whole tutorial.

Comment: this worked! im still figuring out how to display them in my listView adapter! hey Thanks for your help!